# C: Using select() to write to new client

Tags: c, sockets, unix, select, tcp

I'm creating a chat server/client using C and I'm using `select()` to monitor my sockets.

The program is separated into 3 parts, the server, the viewing client. and the submitting client. The submitting client connects a socket to the server and when there is text to be read from the client, select triggers that it needs to be read. If it's a new client connection, select will also trigger so that I can accept the connection and assign a socket to the client.

My issue is with the viewing client which is supposed to trigger select when it is writable. However, when there is a new connection, select doesn't do anything.[This](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_53/apis/sselect.htm) source claims that select will only be triggered on write-fd if they have already been connected. However, how can I connect a new writing client?

server:

```
if (select(128, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL) == -1){
    ...
}

if (FD_ISSET(viewing_socket, &write_fds)){
    printf("%d is a new observer connection\n", viewing_socket);
    new_observer_connection();
}
if (FD_ISSET(submitting_socket, &read_fds)){
    printf("%d is a new participant connection\n", submitting_socket);
    new_participant_connection();
}
```

So when a new submitting client connect, it accepts the connection and adds that new socket to &read_fds to monitor for reads. However, new viewing client connections don't seem to trigger a thing.

Comment: "This source' doesn't say that at all. It doesn't say 'only'. Writability will also trigger when the connect completes if you did the connect in non-blocking mode. I'm have a hard time following your description. Please clarify which component owns which socket and is calling `select()` at each stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seconds after posting this I found the solution. The listening sockets both need to be read from when there is a new client. Only after accepting the connection does the new socket get watched for writing. The socket listening for new connections obviously needs to be read from not written to. Will keep this up for others...

Comment: The only times you should add a socket to the write `select` set is when a previous `write` operation fails with an `EWOULDBLOCK` or when for some reason it's much easier to do it that way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So what is the proper way to tell when a socket is ready to be written to? Or is select not the best thing to use in this scenario?

Comment: Using `select` is fine when you need to tell when a socket is ready to be written to. But until a `send` fails with an `EWOULDBLOCK`, you don't need to know when the socket is ready to be written to.